# Regex and getText()

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a pattern in a `JTextPane` text which I retrieve via `getText()`

```
Pattern p=null;
Matcher m=null;
patt="whatever";
p=Pattern.compile(patt);
m=p.matcher(editeur.getText());
boolean iscurrent_Match=m.matches();
System.out.println(iscurrent_Match);
```

This always gives `false`, no matter what `whatever` is. I also tried `\bwhatever\b` but it never works. Is there any issue with `getText()`? I printed it on screen and it seemed right

Example:

```
patt="write"
```

`editeur.getText()` is a fortran code, for example

```
call random_seed ( GET = seed ) 
write ( *, '(a)' ) ' ' 
write ( *, '(a)' ) ' The current seed is ' 
write ( *, '(5i12)' ) 
seed(1:n) 
write ( *, '(a)' ) ' We reset the seed to ' 
write ( *, '(5i12)' ) 
seed_save(1:n)
```

Comment: Print out the bytes of the text to see exactly what it's holding.

Comment: Can you provide an example for the value of ``patt`` and the return value of ``getText()`` that is supposed to be working?

Comment: Don't try to post code in a comment, instead [edit] your question to add it there.

Comment: Did you try `=m.find()`? `matches()` requires a full string match.